# PHP process eats all the memory

Tags: php, memory

For example I have a function witch gets products from database, I am calling in parts by categories, because without that it will eat all memory. So when I calling in parts memory is not cleared and it starts another process which eats more memory. I could separate by files, but I need more convenient method.

```
function getproducts($cat){
    error_log("START | ".$cat." | MEMORY: ".formatBytes(memory_get_usage(true)), 0);
    $args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $cat
            )
        ),
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1

    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    error_log("QTY: ".$the_query->found_posts." | Mem: ".formatBytes(memory_get_usage(true)), 0);
    error_log("END | MEMORY: ".formatBytes(memory_get_usage(true)), 0);
}
getproducts('part1');
getproducts('part2');
getproducts('part3');
```

log info:

```
[17-Jan-2020 09:33:07 UTC] START | part1 | MEMORY: 2 MB
[17-Jan-2020 09:33:14 UTC] QTY: 3151 | Mem: 198 MB
[17-Jan-2020 09:33:14 UTC] END | MEMORY: 198 MB
[17-Jan-2020 09:33:14 UTC] START | part2 | MEMORY: 198 MB
[17-Jan-2020 09:33:15 UTC] QTY: 533 | Mem: 204 MB
[17-Jan-2020 09:33:15 UTC] END | MEMORY: 204 MB
```

As you can see memory is suming up.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `posts_per_page` for "splitting" your request arg?

Comment: PHP's memory cleanup process only runs when it needs to i.e. memory is nearly all used, or occasionally on a sort of timed basis. This is normal. You would not want PHP to spend all its time checking memory when it should be doing something useful like running your code

Comment: I don't see any problem with 0.2 GB

Comment: about 0.2 GB this is just example, I told that it eats all memory and can't do the task. Johannes could you show little example on spliting?

Comment: Instead of setting `posts_per_page` to `-1` (no limit), set it to a desired value (e.g. `6`) and add the `paged` parameter with the current page number (could be a parameter of your function `getproducts`). A good tutorial (but in German): [kulturbanause.de](https://blog.kulturbanause.de/2016/03/wp_query-mit-pagination/) and the official documentation in the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22Paged.22_Parameter_to_a_Query).

Comment: Thanks codex for reply, but this is for pagination, I don't know if it will work like that.

Comment: I understood it like you split the number of all posts by assigning different terms to them, right? What are you trying to achieve actually?

Comment: This is just for clearing products.

Comment: Then I don't get what you are trying to achieve. Could you maybe upload this part of your project or share a link where we can test this? Furthermore, which fields does a `product` contain? Can you share the `var_dump()` for one product please?